# RegEx slows down if text not read from RichTextBox

Tags: regex, vb.net, richtextbox

I found a strange issue with the combination of RichTextBox and RegEx.
If I load a text file into a RichTextBox and use

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text, "^H(.+\t){10}\n", RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

then the RegEx will run blazing fast.
OTOH if I load the text from a file straight into a string and feed this string with RegEx.Matches using

```
Dim FullText As String = New StreamReader("c:\Temp\TextFile.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, True).ReadToEnd
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(FullText, "^H(.+\t){10}\n", RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

then the regex will run for ages.

Now obviously the RichTextBox does something to the text. I found that loading the text into the RichTextBox will eliminate the first 4 bytes of the text (is that the byte order mark?). However, trimming those 4 characters with SubString won't solve the problem. RichTextBox does some other processing that I'm unaware of.

I'm using RegEx both on client and server side (client can load text files into a RichTextBox to test and setup various RegEx's and the server will process text files according to these previously setup RegEx's). Needless to say that a regex will run blazing fast on the text file loaded into a RichTextBox, while the very same RegEx ran through the very same text file will seem to lock up the server side service.

My question: what kind of text processing does the RichTextBox do and how can I mimic the behavior in a server-side process?

Thank you for your kind help in advance.

Best Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Just guesses:

1. For measuring the time, are you counting the time to load the file from the disk?  The time to load a file might be longer than the time to run the regex.
2. Maybe it has something to do with Unicode?  Maybe the representation of the string in the RichTextBox is somehow faster to process than the one in the variable?  You could test it by using a BinaryFormatter to output the each to a list of bytes and see if the bytes are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I step through the code in the debugger. The text file in question is 1800 bytes, so it takes no time to load. The debugger immediately jumps to the next row. However, when reading out MatchCollection.Count (that is the time when the regex is actually processed) it takes about 3-4 minutes to do so. So the difference is quite pronounced. I'll take a look at the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: It turns out that RichTextBox converts \r\n into \n. Once doing the conversion on the string all is OK.